# Positioning Element At Bottom Programmatically

Tags: android

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

layout.addView(this.adView,lp);
```

I'm trying to position my adView at the bottom of my screen. The above appears to just center it.

I was wondering where I was going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use wrap_content as your height & width ?

Comment: Can you paste more code, for example what are the parameters of the PARENT ?

Comment: @ FD_ I have used WRAP_CONTENT and now the ad doesnt appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning your view at the bottom but filling the whole screen like mentioned by FD_. So the content is centered in its view.

Comment: I have used WRAP_CONTENT and now the ad doesnt appear on screen.

Comment: two things: first when you define your `LayoutParams`, you are using inside the brackets `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` for a `RelativeLayout`, second you can also check to define a height if your view does not have a defined height during layout.

Comment: I can;t define a height for the view as it's provided by an ad server, also changing Linear to Relative does not fix the issue

Comment: add gravity bottom to it and keep it match_parent (not layout-gravity!)

Comment: lp.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); does not compile: The method setGravity(int) is undefined for the type RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

Comment: The method setGravity(int) is undefined for the type AdLayout

Comment: I do not know your Class. The idea behind is to apply the gravity on the content of the adview and not on the layout of it. On views `apply` can also work. Can you post your class definition?

Comment: public class mYActivity extends Activity implements AdListener{

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

to:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Notice that I also changed LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: Did you see that WRAP_CONTENT was not the only thing that I changed?

Comment: Yes, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: You are also making sure to setLayoutParams(lp) on your view right?

Comment: Yes:  layout.addView(this.adView,lp);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34463/discussion-between-adam-johns-and-user1013512)